# setting the float value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I'm having trouble setting something to float right in JS. My code is as follows:

```
var closebutton = document.createElement('div');
closebutton.style.styleFloat = "right";
alert(closebutton.style.styleFloat);
closebutton.style.background = "#f00";
closebutton.innerHTML = '<a href="">&#10006;</a>';
titlebar.appendChild(closebutton);
```

The background of the element is indeed red, and when loaded the page alerts "right". Yet the div is not floated right. Firebug shows no trace of the float. There are no errors or warnings in the Error Console.

I'm stumped!

**Update:**
As suggested, I have also tried:

```
closebutton.style.float = 'right';
```

This also does not work, and is highlighted bright red in my text-editor (gedit)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard way to set the float style in JavaScript is to use the `cssFloat` property:

```
closebutton.style.cssFloat = 'right';
```

That works in all browsers, but not in IE, which expects the `styleFloat` property instead. Therefore you can either detect the browser, and apply the appropriate property, or else set them both:

```
closebutton.style.styleFloat = 'right';
closebutton.style.cssFloat = 'right';
```

Note that `float` is a reserved word in JavaScript, and cannot be used in the dot notation. The same applies for `class`, for example, which is another reserved word. That's why there is a different name for CSS properties that conflict with JavaScript reserved words ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:en/CSS/float)).

Further reading:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: float CSS Proeprty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float)

Comment: Those words where in my head the minute I saw the question title - you're a long-distance MIND-READER!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `closebutton.style.float`, use `closebutton.style.cssFloat`

Reference: [W3C Style Object Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_cssfloat.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`closebutton.style.float = 'right';` just works now.

`style.cssFloat` is no longer needed.