# Javascript change the style of all <a> in an list

Tags: javascript

How can I best change the float property of all the  elements in a list?

```
<ul id="selected">
<li><a>Item</a></li>
<li><a>Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `getElementsByTagName()` to find all the `<a>` elements, iterate over them in a `for` loop, and set the style.

Comment: The best way to do it would be using CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: What if OP has a condition when special styling must be applied? If that's not the case, then I agree that you should use css. But if not, you can use `getElementsByTagName` as mentioned above but I'd recommend defining a specific class rather than directly applying styling to the elements.

Comment: I have to use javascript, obviously this for a dynamic circumstance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. The idea is basically what [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) suggested in his first comment.

```
[].forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('#selected a'),
    function(value) { value.style.cssFloat = 'left'; }
);
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/4YFhj/)

Comment: This is what I was looking for thanks, btw you need to use cssFloat for it to work in FF, float is a reserved word.

Comment: @user1209203 Glad I could help. And thank you for the hint. According to this question "[setting the float value from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3443379/1456376)" you may have to set it even different for older IE versions.