# How to change float style of list tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having problems changing the float styling of a list tag using javascript. I am making a website and trying to make it responsive so that when the screen size is below 600px, there is a hamburger icon that can be pressed and the navigation bar appears, however I have set the float to left in the css code so that when the window is above 600px the menu stays horizontal. I am now trying to change it so that when the hamburger is pressed and the menu appears, each list element appears below each other, rather than next to each other.

This is my div for the navigation bar:

```js
count = 1;

function clickHamburger() {
  var navigation = document.getElementById('navigation');
  var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  if (count % 2 != 0) {
    navigation.style.display = 'block';
    count++;
  } else if (count % 2 == 0) {
    navigation.style.display = 'none';
    li.style.styleFloat = 'none';
    count++;
  }
}
```

```css
#navigation {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(106, 106, 241);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #navigation {
    display: none;
  }
  #hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 599px) {
  #navigation {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='hamburger'><img id=imgham src="hamburger.png" onclick='clickHamburger();' /></div>

<div id='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">XML Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Slideshow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443379/setting-the-float-value-from-javascript

Comment: tried cssFloat bus doesnt work either

Comment: Three things here really - 1. hide/show the div, 2. Set the CSS float 3. determine the width for the responsive.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an `HtmlCollection` of all your `li` elements which are 5 here. So you need to loop through them and set the style. You are also setting float to `none` where the menu is getting closed. I think you want to move it to the other if block where the navigation is set to display. The correct property name is `cssFloat`. `styleFloat` is the property name in IE 8 and lower.

```
count=1;
function clickHamburger () {
    var navigation = document.getElementById('navigation');
    var liElems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    if (count % 2 != 0) {
        navigation.style.display = 'block';
        for (var i = 0; i < liElems.length; i++) {
            liElems[i].style.cssFloat = 'none';
        }
        count++;
    } else if (count % 2 == 0) {
        navigation.style.display = 'none';
        count++;
    }
}
```

Last but not least the recommended method to handle styles using javascript is by adding and removing classes. For example:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('navigation');
setTimeout(() => div.classList.add('red'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => div.classList.remove('blue'), 2000);
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
 
.blue {
  border: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation" class="blue">DIV</div>
```

You can add and remove classes on your navigation element and control the style of children using css.